# Turn array of objects into structured object?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

Ok so I have an array of objects that looks similar to this:

```
[
   {
     id: "001",
     name: "foo",
     parent: null
   },
   {
     id: "002",
     name: "bar",
     parent: "001"
   },
   {
     id: "003",
     name: "foo2",
     parent: null
   },
   {
     id: "004",
     name: "bar2",
     parent: "003"
   },
   {
     id: "005",
     name: "foobar",
     parent: "004"
   },
]
```

and I need to turn it into this:

```
{
    "001": {
        "002": {}
       },
    "003": {
        "004": {
             "005": {}
            }
         }
}
```

So I need to take that array and turn it into a structured object where each object is nested into its parent object. If an object has no children then it is an empty object.

I hope that makes sense. I just can't wrap my head around how to do this.

Comment: what happens to `name`? please add this in the wanted result. btw, what have you tried?

Comment: I do not need the name afterwards as I will be getting the name back from the database later. I haven't actually really tried anything yet, I'm still struggling to come up with a plan.